# Exercise 7(a) on p.111 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Is my solution ok or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, continuity

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

I solved Exercise 7(a) on p.111.
But I am not sure my solution is ok or not because this exercise is too complicated for me.
Is my solution ok or not?

> Exercise 7 on p.111:
>
> Prove the following:
>
> **Theorem.** Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $D$ be the set of points of $S$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Let $E$ be the set of points of $\operatorname{Bd}S$ at which the condition $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0$$ fails to hold. Then $\int_S f$ exists if and only if $D$ and $E$ have measure zero.
>
> Proof.
>
> (a) Show that $f_S$ is continuous at each point $x_0\notin D\cup E$.
>
> (b) Let $B$ be the set of isolated points of $S$; then $B\subset E$ because the limit cannot be defined if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $S$. Show that if $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $x_0\notin D\cup (E-B)$.
>
> (c) Show that $B$ is countable.
>
> (d) Complete the proof.

My solution is the following:
(a) $\mathbb{R}^n-(D\cup E)=(\operatorname{Ext}S-(D\cup E))\cup (\operatorname{Bd}S-(D\cup E)\cup (\operatorname{Int}S-(D\cup E)))$.

---

(a-1) If $x_0\in\operatorname{Ext}S-(D\cup E)=\operatorname{Ext}S$, then $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$ because $f_S$ is the zero function on the open set $\operatorname{Ext}S$.

---

(a-2) If $x_0\in\operatorname{Bd}S-(D\cup E)$, then $x_0\in\operatorname{Bd}S-E$.
So, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$.
So, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that \begin{equation}0<|x-x_0|<\delta\text{ and }x\in S\implies |f(x)-0|<\varepsilon.\tag{1}\end{equation}
If $x\in S$, then $|f_S(x)-0|=|f(x)-0|$ and if $x\notin S$, then $|f_S(x)-0|=|0-0|$.
So, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\begin{equation}0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f_S(x)-0|<\varepsilon.\tag{2}\end{equation}$
If $x_0\notin S$, then $f_S(x_0)=0$.
So, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{3}\end{equation}$
So, $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$ in this case.
If $x_0\in S$, then $x_0\in S-D$.
So, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\text{ and }x\in S\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{4}\end{equation}$
By (1) and (4), for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\begin{equation}0<|x-x_0|<\delta\text{ and }x\in S\implies |f(x)-0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\text{ and }|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.\tag{5}\end{equation}$
So, $|f(x_0)|=|(f(x)-0)-(f(x)-f(x_0))|\leq |f(x)-0|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$.
So, $f(x_0)=0$.
If $x\in S$, then $|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ and if $x\notin S$, then $|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|=|0-f(x_0)|=|0-0|$.
So, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{6}\end{equation}$
So, $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$ in this case too.

---

(a-3) If $x_0\in\operatorname{Int}S-(D\cup E)=\operatorname{Int}S-D$, then for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta_1$ such that $\begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta_1\text{ and }x\in S\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{7}\end{equation}$
Since $x_0\in\operatorname{Int}S$, there exists a positive real number $\delta_2$ such that \begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta_2\implies x\in S.\tag{8}\end{equation}
Let $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.
Then, \begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\implies x\in S\text{ and }|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{9}\end{equation}
If $x\in S$, then $|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(x_0)|$.
So, \begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{10}\end{equation}
So, $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$ in this case.

Comment: You are using the Riemann integral. In this case, $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $g$ has bounded support, $g$ is bounded, and the set of discontinuities of $g$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. You need to apply this to $g = f1_S$.

Comment: Using Lebesgue's integral, you get a different simpler answer.

Comment: @Mason Thank you very much for your comments.